# How to make RedisQueueMessageDrivenEndpoint work with IntegrationFlow?

Tags: spring-integration, dsl

I would like to know how I can possibly make the RedisQueueMessageDrivenEndpoint work with IntegrationFlow, so I can receive messages dequeued from the list to which it is specified in the following code? The "redisRpopChannel()" does not seem to receive any messages at all. Please help.

```
@Bean
public RedisOutboundGateway redisOutboundGateway(RedisConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
    RedisOutboundGateway gateway = new RedisOutboundGateway(connectionFactory);
    Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer<? extends JsonNode> serializer = new Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer<>(JsonNode.class);
    gateway.setArgumentsSerializer(serializer);
    return gateway;
}

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow redisLpushRequestFlow(RedisOutboundGateway gateway, BeanFactory beanFactory) {
    ExpressionArgumentsStrategy strategy = new ExpressionArgumentsStrategy(new String[]{"headers.queue", "#cmd == 'LPUSH' ? payload : null"}, true);
    strategy.setBeanFactory(beanFactory);
    gateway.setArgumentsStrategy(strategy);
    return flow -> flow.publishSubscribeChannel(s->s.subscribe(f -> f
            .enrich(e -> e.<ObjectNode>requestPayload(m -> {
                String partition = m.getHeaders().get("correlationId").toString();
                ObjectNode objectNode = m.getPayload();
                objectNode.put(PayLoadKeys.PARTITION, partition);
                objectNode.put(PayLoadKeys.SEQ, m.getHeaders().get("sequenceNumber").toString());
                return objectNode;
            }).shouldClonePayload(false)
                    .header(RedisHeaders.COMMAND, "LPUSH").header("queue", files))
            .handle(gateway).channel("redisLpushResponseFlow.input")));
}

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow redisLpushResponseFlow() {
    return flow -> flow.resequence().aggregate().<List<Long>>handle((p,h)-> {
                ObjectNode objectNode = mapper.createObjectNode();
                objectNode.put(PayLoadKeys.PARTITION, h.get("correlationId").toString());
                if(h.get("mode").equals("debug")) {
                    objectNode.set(PayLoadKeys.DEBUG,
                            mapper.valueToTree(p.stream().collect(Collectors.toList())));
                }
                return objectNode;
            }).channel(httpInboundReplyChannel());
@Bean
public MessageChannel redisRpopChannel() {
    return MessageChannels.queue().get();
}

@Bean(name = PollerMetadata.DEFAULT_POLLER)
public PollerMetadata poller() {
    return Pollers.fixedRate(500).get();
}

@Bean
public RedisQueueMessageDrivenEndpoint redisQueueMessageDrivenEndpoint(RedisConnectionFactory connectionFactory, BeanFactory beanFactory) {
    RedisQueueMessageDrivenEndpoint endpoint = new RedisQueueMessageDrivenEndpoint(files, connectionFactory);
    Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer<? extends JsonNode> serializer = new Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer<>(JsonNode.class);
    endpoint.setSerializer(serializer);
    endpoint.setBeanFactory(beanFactory);
    endpoint.setAutoStartup(true);
    endpoint.setOutputChannel(redisRpopChannel());
    endpoint.afterPropertiesSet();
    endpoint.start();
    return endpoint;
}

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow redisQueuePollingFlow() {

    class ThrottledTaskExecutor implements TaskExecutor {
        final Semaphore semaphore;
        final TaskExecutor taskExecutor;

        ThrottledTaskExecutor(ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor) {
            this.taskExecutor = taskExecutor;
            this.semaphore = new Semaphore(taskExecutor.getCorePoolSize());
        }

        @Override
        public void execute(Runnable task) {
            if (task == null) {
                throw new NullPointerException("Task is null in ThrottledTaskExecutor.");
            }
            doSubmit(task);
        }

        void doSubmit(final Runnable task) {
            try {
                semaphore.acquire();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                throw new TaskRejectedException("Task could not be submitted because of a thread interruption.");
            }
            try {
                taskExecutor.execute(new FutureTask<Void>(task, null) {

                    @Override
                    protected void done() {
                        semaphore.release();
                    }
                });
            } catch (TaskRejectedException e) {
                semaphore.release();
                throw e;
            }
        }
    }

    return IntegrationFlows
            .from(redisRpopChannel())
            .transform(Transformers.fromJson(ObjectNode.class))
            .handle(message -> {
                ObjectNode p = (ObjectNode) message.getPayload();
                ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor = taskExecutor();
                ThrottledTaskExecutor throttledTaskExecutor = new ThrottledTaskExecutor(taskExecutor);
                if(p.hasNonNull(PayLoadKeys.ID_ARRAY)) {
                    String array = p.remove(PayLoadKeys.ID_ARRAY).asText();
                    if (p.hasNonNull(array)) {
                        p.remove(array).forEach(id -> {
                            ObjectNode param = p.deepCopy();
                            final Long finalId = id.asLong();
                            param.put("id", finalId);
                            throttledTaskExecutor.execute(new JobLaunchTask(param));
                        });
                    }
                } else {
                    throttledTaskExecutor.execute(new JobLaunchTask(p));
                }
                taskExecutor.shutdown();
            }).get();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is currently [a problem](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-3910) when using message-driven endpoints (that are defined as `@Bean`s) in the DSL.

The problem is an output channel is required during initialization. However, when the endpoint is later wired into a flow, that channel will be replaced.

You should not be calling methods like `afterPropertiesSet()` and `start()` within a `@Bean` definition.

This worked for me...

```
@Bean
public RedisConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
    JedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory = new JedisConnectionFactory();
    jedisConnectionFactory.setPort(6379);
    return jedisConnectionFactory;
}

@Bean
public RedisQueueMessageDrivenEndpoint redisQueueMessageDrivenEndpoint(RedisConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
    RedisQueueMessageDrivenEndpoint endpoint = new RedisQueueMessageDrivenEndpoint("foo", connectionFactory);
    Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer<? extends JsonNode> serializer = new Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer<>(JsonNode.class);
    endpoint.setSerializer(serializer);
    endpoint.setAutoStartup(true);
    endpoint.setOutputChannel(new DirectChannel()); // will be replaced
    return endpoint;
}

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow flow(RedisConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(redisQueueMessageDrivenEndpoint(connectionFactory))
            .handle(System.out::println)
            .get();
}
```

I tested it with `> lpush foo '{"foo":"bar"}'` in redis-cli.

**EDIT**

However, your technique works too (for me) ...

```
@Bean
public RedisQueueMessageDrivenEndpoint redisQueueMessageDrivenEndpoint(RedisConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
    RedisQueueMessageDrivenEndpoint endpoint = new RedisQueueMessageDrivenEndpoint("foo", connectionFactory);
    Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer<? extends JsonNode> serializer = new Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer<>(JsonNode.class);
    endpoint.setSerializer(serializer);
    endpoint.setAutoStartup(true);
    endpoint.setOutputChannel(rpopChannel());
    return endpoint;
}

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow flow(RedisConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(rpopChannel())
            .handle(System.out::println)
            .get();
}

@Bean
public MessageChannel rpopChannel() {
    return new DirectChannel();
}
```

Again, I removed all the container-managed properties from the endpoint; Spring sets all those.

Comment: Thank you for your review. I really appreciated it very much. I really admire your work too. I wonder why there is no Protocol Adapters which supports iterations with redis and added to the group, so we could all write like IntegrationFlows.from( Redis.inboundGateway(connectionFactory, queue)) ?

Comment: We have limited resources. We ask the community to help us prioritize adding first class support for Redis etc to the DSL, via [JIRA](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INTEXT). Feel free to open an improvement issue there and we'll see what we can do. We also welcome [contributions](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md).